# Passing parameters to constructor of a service using Dependency Injection?

Tags: angular

I have custom service class:

```
@Injectable()

export class CustomService {
  constructor(num: number) {
  }
}
```

This class is injected in constructor of component like this:

```
constructor(private cs: CustomService) {
}
```

But how to pass parameter `num` to service in constructor described above?
Something like that:

```
constructor(private cs: CustomService(1)) {
}
```

I know as solution I can use Fabric pattern, but is there only one way to do that?

Comment: Off topic, but why do you want to create a stateful service? Services should be stateless and should know nothing about their clients

Comment: Otherwise how to pass parameters(settings) to service? Service must work with some incoming data is not it?

Comment: You can't. Consider providing the example that explains what's your case. Yes, it will likely be a variation of factory.

Comment: Then how to use services right? Is it just set of functions? Does it mean that service can not have constructor? How to put any data in Service then?

Comment: @Daniel you would generally configure the service at the module level, with `useFactory`, not where it's injected. Read https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `CustomService` instances should not be injector singletons, it is:

```
providers: [{ provide: CustomService, useValue: CustomService }]

...

private cs;

constructor(@Inject(CustomService) private CustomService: typeof CustomService) {
  this.cs = new CustomService(1);
}
```

If `CustomService` is supposed be memoized to return singletons for respective parameter, instances should be retrieved through additional cache service:

```
class CustomServiceStorage {
  private storage = new Map();

  constructor(@Inject(CustomService) private CustomService: typeof CustomService) {}
  get(num) {
    if (!this.storage.has(num))
      this.storage.set(num, new this.CustomService(num));

    return this.storage.get(num);
  }
}
```

Comment: Where to write this `providers: [{ provide: CustomService, useValue: CustomService }]`? What does it mean?

Comment: It depends on your case. In NgModule or Component. See [the manual](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#injector-providers). `useValue` means that CustomService will be injected as a class and won't be instantiated by injector.

Comment: You can check [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44301253/3731501) that uses the same recipe for example.

Answer (score 0):

A service can hold data. You could define a public property in your service and set that data.

Here is an example:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable() 
export class DataService {
  serviceData: string; 
}
```

But if you are configuring the service, Jon's comment to your question may be a better solution.